# SQLAlchemy hybrid property expression datetime conversion

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy with python 2.7.

I'm trying to create a property which I can use in a query to order by. I already learned I should use a `hybrid_property` for this with the according expression but I'm having trouble getting a `timedelta` object in the expression.

The query I want to execute is something like `Article.query.filter(Article.language == language).order_by(Article.popularity.desc())`

with

```
from math import exp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'articles'
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # ...
    language = db.Column(db.String(64), default='en')
    date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    readers_frac = db.Column(db.Float, default=0.)

    @hybrid_property
    def popularity(self):
        # compute the popularity based on the readers_frac and the time in minutes since the article was published
        min_since_published = (datetime.utcnow() - self.date_time).total_seconds()/60.
        popularity_decay = exp(-(min_since_published**2 / (2.*1832.4**2)))
        return self.readers_frac*popularity_decay

    @popularity.expression
    def popularity(cls):
        # compute the popularity based on the readers_frac and the time in minutes since the article was published
        min_since_published = (datetime.utcnow() - cls.date_time).seconds/60.
        popularity_decay = exp(-(min_since_published**2 / (2.*1832.4**2)))
        return cls.readers_frac*popularity_decay
```

However I'm getting the error `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'seconds'` when trying to compute `min_since_published`. Any hints? Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

I fixed it by changing everything to `sqlalchemy.func` expressions, i.e. it works (with a mysql backend) with

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
@popularity.expression
def popularity(cls):
     # compute the popularity based on the readers_frac and the time in minutes since the article was published
    min_since_published = sa.func.timestampdiff(sa.text('MINUTE'), cls.date_time, sa.func.utc_timestamp())
    popularity_decay = sa.func.exp(-(sa.func.pow(min_since_published, 2) / 6730009.))
    return cls.readers_frac*popularity_decay
```

Comment: Which database are you using? (date/time functionality varies between them substantially)

Comment: That's because `datetime.utcnow() - cls.date_time` is a *SQL expression* and hence does not have `.seconds`, unlike `datetime.utcnow() - self.date_time`, which is a `datetime`. You need to find the corresponding function in your RDBMS that gives you the equivalent functionality. (Same thing with `exp`.)

Comment: Right now I'm using SQLite in the background but later it will be mysql. I was hoping with the sqlalchemy abstraction this wouldn't matter...

Comment: I guess for `exp` I can use `sqlalchemy.func.exp` but I didn't find anything to get and work with an equivalent of a `datatime.timedelta` object...

Comment: @cod3licious You can add your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned it really depends on the database backend you're using for this and which functions it provides. For example sqlite would not work as the database itself just doesn't have the capabilities to answer the query, but mysql does. Then it's really just about looking how the function would look like as an original mysql query statement and translating this into `sqlalchemy.func` expressions. This works:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
@popularity.expression
def popularity(cls):
    # compute the popularity based on the readers_frac and the time in minutes since the article was published
    min_since_published = sa.func.timestampdiff(sa.text('MINUTE'), cls.date_time, sa.func.utc_timestamp())
    popularity_decay = sa.func.exp(-(sa.func.pow(min_since_published, 2) / 6730009.))
    return cls.readers_frac*popularity_decay
```